Experimental liimits on torque free precession of spin?
Inspired by this question, I'd like to know what experimental limits there are on the torque-free precession of particle spin. This is a classical phenomenon, not part of quantum theory, but only experiments can verify if this omission is correct.

What is the Muon g-2 Experiment? w/ Don Lincoln

The physics of g-2

@mmesser314 How does that limit torque-free precession? The experiments involve ordinary torqued precession.

I think this boils down to asking about violations of the conservation of angular momentum. I didn't find any papers specifically trying to constrain this effect doing a google search, but one experiment that comes to mind would be a torsion balance, any non-conservation of angular momentum above the measured gravitational torque would ruin that experiment. You'd also have to wonder what axis the spin would precess around in the absence of a torque.

@Andrew Torque-free precession conserves angular momentum. It occurs when a body is rotating around an axis that isn't one of the principal axes of its inertia tensor. In that case, the rotation and angular momentum axes are not aligned, and while the angular momentum axis is fixed, the rotation axis isn't. The rotation axis precesses about the angular momentum axis.

@JohnDoty Oh ok, I thought you meant precession of the angular momentum vector (which is what I would call particle spin). In that case, why do you want experimental limits? The effect you're describing does actually occur.

@Andrew It occurs for rigid bodies. Does it occur for particle spin? Can some other manifestation of particle orientation, the magnetic dipole moment for example, become misaligned versus its angular momentum vector?

I'm not sure I understand. I know you know magnetic north for the Earth doesn't align with the Earth's spin vector, and the Earth exhibits the torque-free precession you're talking about (Chandler wobble) for example. But do you mean the spin of a fundamental particle? But then this is surely a question about quantum mechanics?

@Andrew It's an experimental question about elementary particles. I realize that in quantum mechanics, particles lack anything resembling an inertia tensor, but is this justified by experiments?
